# Is there a better way to write this set of IF statements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

There are a couple spots in my code where I need to test for true on multiple different variables - like so:

```
if(setting1){ Do something with El A };
if(setting2){ Do something with El B };
if(setting3){ Do something with El C };
if(setting4){ Do something with El D };
```

Is there a better way of writing this?

**I've updated the question with extra details, but it looks like the block of IFs is the best option.**

Settings are saved to .data. These settings are true/false and they enable/disable HTML elements. At certain points in my script, I need to check these elements to see if they're enabled before running some additional code. For example, showing the elements - if the user has set the .data for the Nav Button to true - then the Nav button will be shown.

```
if(setting1){ Do A to El A };
```

There isn't really a pattern to the code inside the condition, so I don't think a loop is a good solution. Again, I think a block of IFs is the best way to go, but I'm curious if there's some kind of cool trick to write this cleaner.

```
if(setting1){ Do A to El A};
if(setting2){ Do B to El B};
if(setting3){ Do A to El A};
if(setting4){ Do X to El X};
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is `Do something` the same something for each?

Comment: No, they're all slightly different

Comment: @Aaron Can we see how they're different? They're often combinable.

Comment: are you hinting at a loop?

Comment: There are several different instances that this occurs throughout my script. These are used to test if the user has enabled/disabled an element. And since I'm working with about 10 specific elements, I need to test if they've enabled the element, then run some code. The code is specific to each element. Hope that helps a bit. A loop won't work in this situation though because the code is a bit different. If you weren't hinting at a loop and I just jumped the gun - apologies :p

Comment: Is the means of determining enabled/disabled the same for each element? And is it always the same 10 elements? And are all the elements always analysed and invoked (if enabled) at the same time?

Comment: @Aaron: If your situation meets the [@thesystem's requirements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15036452/is-there-a-better-way-to-write-this-set-of-if-statements#comment21133467_15036452) then you should probably use a loop. Just make an array of those elements, then loop: `elements.forEach(function(el) { alert(el.disabled); });`

Comment: they're invoked elsewhere in the script and I have several sections throughout the script that test what elements are enabled, then performn various actions... so far it doesn't looks like there's an adequate solution to this and a block of ifs is the best way... it just doesn't look right

Comment: @Web_Designer ... a loop would work well, but then inside the loop I'd still be having to check what object it is. Say I'm looping through the array and if index = 1 then do something with El1, etc. I don't see how this would be better....

Comment: @Aaron You don't need to check the index of each item if you use [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead of a regular `for` loop.

Comment: @Aaron: Is the code that runs for each element always the same?

Comment: @Web_Designer Nice! if you put this as an answer I can accept it :) Thanks! That will do the trick nicely

Comment: @Aaron Your welcome. Here's [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15036761/552067). Happy JavaScript-ing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to loop through each element checking if it's disabled:

```
elements.forEach(function(el) {
    alert(el.disabled);
});
```

Comment: @Aaron: This is exactly what you kept saying wouldn't work. If the code is different for each element, then you're back to your `if` statement.

Comment: @the system you're correct. I checked the link for that was provided and at first it looked like it would work, however I will still have to include an if.... so it seems like the if statement is the best way unless you can recommend anything?

Answer (score 1):

If you're not one for KISS,

```
var settingsAndEffects = 
[
    {'test': function(params) { return bool; }, // setting1
        'apply': function(params) { ... }}, // Do something with El A
    {'test': function(params) { return bool; }, // setting2
        'apply': function(params) { ... }}, // Do something with El B
    ...
]

for(var i = 0; i < settingsAndEffects.length; i++) 
{
    if(settingsAndEffects[i].test(params))
        settingsAndEffects[i].apply(params);
}
```

otherwise stick with the ifs.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `switch` statement ... [filler text here]

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: I was thinking about that, but will the switch statement drop out after it's run a case? This needs to test conditions for each one...

Comment: Yep, a switch does normally break out. If you need to perform every test, then (depending on context) you probably have the clearest method.

Answer (score 0):

If `settingsX` are arbitrary, `Do something` too, and there's no relation whatsoever between a setting and an element, a setting and the code or the element and the code, then I believe your code is minimal. I could suggest many alternative ways of expressing them - which may help promote reuse, but not make the code smaller - but I'd need more info about the context.

For instance, if both the code and the settings is specific to the element:

```
$("#elementA").data("DoSomething", function() { ... });
$("#elementB").data("DoSomething", function() { ... });

$(".my_elements")
    .filter(function() { return specificSettings(this); })
    .each(function() { $(this).data("DoSomething")(); });
```

Note that the resulting code is more verbose, so it's only an advantage if you're reusing it in several places.